# Qt 5.4.2 build issue with -no-angle -no-opengl on msvc2010

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2010, opengl, nmake

As stated in header, I'm experiencing strange behaviour during Qt 5.4.2 build process.

I want to get qt to be able compile binaries with static libs so here is my `configure` options:

```
configure -static -release -platform win32-msvc2010 -qt-sql-db2 -qt-sql-odbc
-no-angle -no-opengl
```

At first there was no `-no-angle -no-opengl`, but I've added it in order to eliminate nmake errors.

However, I still getting opengl build errors even after disabling it in configure!

```
OpenGL support..............no
```

And, after `nmake`:

```
c:\qt-src-5.4.2\qtbase\include\qtgui\5.4.2\qtgui\private\../../../../../src/gui/
opengl/qopenglextensions_p.h(147) : error C2059: syntax error: )
c:\qt-src-5.4.2\qtbase\include\qtgui\5.4.2\qtgui\private\../../../../../src/gui/
opengl/qopenglextensions_p.h(147) : error C2061: syntax error: identifier
 "GLint"
c:\qt-src-5.4.2\qtbase\include\qtgui\5.4.2\qtgui\private\../../../../../src/gui/
opengl/qopenglextensions_p.h(147) : fatal error C1003:  error count exceeds 100; 
stopping compilation.
Generating code...
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\
VC\BIN\amd64\cl.EXE" : return code "0x2"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\
VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe" : return code "0x2"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: cd : return code "0x2"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: cd : return code "0x2"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: cd : return code "0x2"
Stop.
```

Also I've tried `-opengl desktop`, but it only leads to similar failure, just a bit after.

With that option Qt tells that:

```
qaccessible.cpp
c:\qt-src-5.4.2\qtbase\include\qtgui\../../src/gui/opengl/qopengl.h(99) : fatal
error C1083: Cannot open include file: GLES2/gl2.h: No such file or dir
ectory
qaccessiblecache.cpp
qaccessibleobject.cpp
qaccessibleplugin.cpp
qplatformaccessibility.cpp
qaccessiblebridge.cpp
Generating code...
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\
VC\BIN\amd64\cl.EXE" : return code "0x2"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\
VC\BIN\amd64\nmake.exe" : return code "0x2"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: cd : return code "0x2"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: cd : return code "0x2"
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: cd : return code "0x2"
Stop.
```

What should I do to get Qt successfully compiled?

Comment: Don't use `nmake` with Qt. Use `jom`. Unsure if that relates to the problem but at least Qt own `jom` is faster due to build parallelization and guaranteed to be compatible with Qt build.

Comment: I did not succeded with solving that issue. Moved to Qt 5.8 and msvc 2015. Seems like msvc2010 is not supported. If there is necessity to use exactly msvc2010 you'd better stick with qt4 variants(qt4.8 worked fine, but it's too old for my purpose)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the path to the director GES which contains various header files in your MSVC project solution. The error indicates missing header files.

Or you could add the directory include like so:

-L"Path/to/GES/directory"

Comment: sorry for late reply. this approach did not work for me though.